# Go MarshalJSON behavior with multiple embedded structs

Tags: go, encoding-json-go

I'm testing out go json marshaling with embedded structs. However, I see that when I embed time.Time, why does it always override the other embedded structs even though they also provide their own custom marshaling? The code below always print out `"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type A struct {
}

func (a A) Print() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}

type B struct {
    B int
}

func (a A) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"a"`), nil
}

func (b B) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"b"`), nil
}

func (a B) Print() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}

type C struct {
    A
    B
    time.Time
    C int `json:"C"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    c := C{}
    decode, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(decode))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you embed multiple types that have identically named fields or methods, then those fields or methods will not be accessible directly anymore.

[Selectors](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors):

> `x.f`
>
> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or
>    interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth
>    in `T` where there is such an `f`. If there is **not exactly one `f`**
>    with shallowest depth, the selector expression **is illegal**.

That means that, given the following set of types:

```golang
type S1 struct { F string }

type S2 struct { F string }

type S3 struct {
    S1
    S2
}
```

the expression `s3.F` is illegal:

```golang
var s3 S3
_ = s3.F // ambiguous selector s3.F
```

this is because there are **more than one `F` at the shallowest depth**. You can try it on [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/i9sen2kK12s).

The same rules apply to methods. From this it follows that your type `C` does NOT satisfy the `json.Marshaler` interface **because** it embeds, at the same depth, **more that one** type that implements the `MarshalJSON()` method. You can see that for yourself on [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tJ7_gxREYYd).

---

Then, however, the question still remains as to why the embedded `time.Time`'s custom marshaling is used regardless. This is because `time.Time` implements not only the `json.Marshaler` interface but also the `encoding.TextMarshaler` interface ([docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.18.1#Time.MarshalText) & [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/abVRwvGKmPY)). And the `json.Marshal`'s [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.1#Marshal) says the following:

> Marshal traverses the value v recursively. If an encountered value
> implements the `Marshaler` interface and is not a nil pointer, Marshal
> calls its `MarshalJSON` method to produce JSON. If no `MarshalJSON` method
> is present **but the value implements `encoding.TextMarshaler` instead,
> Marshal calls its `MarshalText` method and encodes the result as a JSON
> string**.

You can [see here](https://go.dev/play/p/tSClvG44KU1) that the behaviour described above holds once you also have `A` or `B` implement the `encoding.TextMarshaler` interface, then the `time.Time`'s `MarshalText` method will not be used anymore.

Comment: Depending on your use case you can get around this by nesting your embeds; i.e. instead of `type C struct{A;B}` do `type B struct{A}; type C struct{B}`. `C.MarshalJSON` will "bubble up" to the first of `C`, `B`, or `A` that has the method defined. [Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/BIXeSLXYi82)